# varchar data type need to return rows that have certain numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a view using a function that will format the values with a comma between the hundreds and thousands column. Then I need to run a select statement on the view to find items with a value greater than 800. The problem I'm running into is that, when defining the WHERE statement, I am getting the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '17.50' to data type int.

I think it is because of the datatype I've created in the view but I'm unsure how to write it in a way that will allow me to write the select statement to view values < 800 and will maintain the formatting requirements of having a comma between the hundreds and thousands column.

Here's the select statement:

```
SELECT VendorName
FROM VendorStatistics
WHERE InvLineItemTotal < 800
```

Here's the original code for creating thew view:

```
CREATE VIEW VendorStatistics
AS
SELECT VendorName, COUNT(Invoices.InvoiceID) AS CountOfInvoices, CONVERT(varchar, SUM(InvoiceLineItemAmount), 1) AS InvLineItemTotal
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
    ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems
    ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
GROUP BY VendorName
```

Comment: If possible, try to convince someone to change the view definition. Storing numeric information as strings is a bad idea. Just to give one example of where this can cause trouble, note that SELECT VendorStatistics WHERE InvLineItemTotal < 800.0 will *not* return a row of the table that has InvLineItemTotal = '799.95'! Formatting can and should be done only for the final presentation to users.

Comment: I agree, this is for an assignment but it feels like there wouldn't be a business need to write something this way. Is the error maybe in the create view? Is there another way to cast/convert SUM(InvoiceLineItemAmount) to have commas but is still numeric?...

Comment: Numeric values don't have a format, so no, there is no way to store something in a float/real/decimal/int column with a format. There's no *error* per se, but when strings are used in numeric expressions, implicit conversion happens, and not always as expected (witness the fact that '799.95' < 800 is evaluated as FALSE).

Comment: formatting numbers should 100% of the time be done by the aaplication not the database. Storing numbers as strings is always a bad plan unless the number cannot be used mathmatically (phone number, zip code as examples)

Answer (score 0):

Your view should include the original summed numeric field `SUM(InvoiceLineItemAmount) AS InvLineItemTotalNumeric` in its output. Use that field to do your numeric comparison:

```
SELECT VendorName
FROM VendorStatistics
WHERE InvLineItemTotalNumeric < 800
```

Use the formatted field `InvLineItemTotal` for display only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
SELECT VendorName
FROM VendorStatistics
WHERE convert(float, InvLineItemTotal) < 800.0
```

Comment: I received the following error - Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'float'.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type InvLineItemTotal is not a defined system type.

Comment: Borik got the CONVERT backwards. It's convert(float,InvLineItemTotal), or you can use the ANSI standard equivalent CAST(InvLineItemTotal AS float).

Comment: @Steve Kass thank you for correction, edited the post to reflect correct syntax...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea for manuy reasons, but if you must do it for an assignment, then change the view to include both the real number and theformatted number as a string.

```
CREATE VIEW VendorStatistics
AS
SELECT VendorName, COUNT(Invoices.InvoiceID) AS CountOfInvoices, CONVERT(varchar, SUM(InvoiceLineItemAmount), 1) AS InvLineItemTotal, SUM(InvoiceLineItemAmount) as InvoiceLineItemSum
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
    ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems
    ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
GROUP BY VendorName
```

Now you can query:

```
SELECT VendorName
FROM VendorStatistics
WHERE InvoiceLineItemSum < 800.0
```

or even

```
SELECT VendorName, InvLineItemTotal
FROM VendorStatistics
WHERE InvoiceLineItemSum < 800.0
```